# Is a double-yolk egg capable of producing two viable chicks?

Tags: twins, eggs

As per title: If fertilized, is a double-yolk egg capable of producing two viable chicks (that could survive to adulthood)?

Have there been any reported cases of such (presumably) fraternal twins?

Answer (score 2):

According to the discussion [here](http://www.homesteadingtoday.com/livestock-forums/poultry/446574-two-chicks-one-egg.html) they normally fail to hatch because the chicks cannot get enough leverage to break the shell.

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1ZeEY-kt7A) of an assisted hatching. It is claimed that these two survived.

Comment: I wonder then, if someone assisted to break the shell, or the shell was particularly thin, then perhaps they could survive. I was wondering if there would be enough physical room in one shell, although I have noticed that double yolk eggs are typically noticeably larger than normal.